# Async Javascript calls - Await request, execute immediately if it comes in within x time, skip otherwise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working with an API that requires info requests to be made one at a time. If there's multiple requests, I'd like to make an attempt to get them all, but it's an all or nothing situation. If we don't get them all after 2 seconds, move to the next step without them.

I know this is possible using promises, but I keep getting the behavior to either way for them, or forcibly wait 2 seconds, even if it has them all after 1.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly welcome.

Also, it adds the info to a store, so it would be best the api call running in the background to get that info regardless of if the next stage got access to it.

- Payload comes in with key array
- I begin a recursive function to ping API for keys one at a time
- If not all keys are back after 2 seconds, continue the payload to the next step
- Continue the key storing process even if it passes 2 seconds
- If are back early, do not wait for the full 2 seconds

Thanks in advance, truly appreciate any help or implementation suggestions.

Comment: *I know this is possible using promises, but I keep getting the behavior to either way for them* - what did you try?

Comment: to be clear, I'm not very experienced with them. I used an implementation I found at: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/317/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-promise-has-been-fulfilled-rejected-or-resolved but couldn't get it fully functioning. If you have any guide that could easily achieve the same I'd gladly try, but I'm having trouble finding anything myself..

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a good opportunity to use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).  Something on the lines of:

```
const bomb = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 2000));
const data = await Promise.race([bomb, fetch(request)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fetch request wrapped with a promise. Implementation details will vary, however the basic implementation will work like this:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  setTimeout(reject, 2000, 'foo');
  fetch(request).then(resolve).catch(reject);
});
```

For more information go here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

EDIT:
Looking at your quesiton again, I saw that you said you are using Node. This means that you won't want a timeout hanging around in the background. This will happen with Promise.race() or my implementation. Here is a fix to remove the timeout so that your server won't be bogged down with many requests creating and holding timeouts:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  timeout = setTimeout(reject, 2000, 'foo');
  fetch(request)
       .then((res)=>{

       resolve(res);
       clearTimeout(timeout);

    }).catch(reject);
});
```

Comment: Note that this works because JavaScript does not pause. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258012/does-javascript-settimeout-stop-other-script-execution

Answer (score 0):

```
//Either ms gets resolved or rejected in ms
const promiseTimeout = function(ms, promise){

    // Create a promise that rejects in <ms> milliseconds
    let timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let id = setTimeout(() => {
        reject('Timed out in '+ ms + 'ms.')
      }, ms)
    })

    // Returns a race between our timeout and the passed in promise
    return Promise.race([
      promise,
      timeout
    ])
  }


var resolvedPromisesArray = [Promise.resolve(call1), Promise.resolve(call2)];

var p = Promise.all(resolvedPromisesArray);

console.log(promiseTimeout(2000,p));
```

Have a look at the above piece. Either both call 1 and call2 get resolved or the function waits for 2 secs and times out issuing a reject. To learn more promises, use MDN or check out https://italonascimento.github.io/applying-a-timeout-to-your-promises/

Comment: Why would you clear the timeout inside of the timeout's callback? That callback only executes after the timeout you are clearing is already "cleared". Basically it wouldn't even do anything.